# Metricbeat creating huge number of fields

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I installed metricbeat on a unix server and it's mapping generate a massive number of fields. If there a way to disable them? I would like a default index to only create mappings for a unix "system" module mappings and windows "windows" module mappings.

In my yml I am only showing something like this

```
metricbeat.modules:
- module: system
  period: 1m
  metricsets:
    - cpu
    - load
    - memory
    #- network
    - process
    - process_summary
    #- core
    #- diskio
    #- socket
  processes: ['.*']

- module: system
  period: 10m
  metricsets:
    - filesystem
    - fsstat
  processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'

- module: system
  period: 15m
  metricsets:
    - uptime
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Metricbeat automatically loads the recommended template file, fields.yml, if the Elasticsearch output is enabled. thus  in order to customize your fields write a NewFieldsFile.yml file that contains all the required  fields and change the default one in the **metricbeat.yml** config file to:

```
setup.template.name: "your_template_name"
setup.template.fields: "path/to/NewFieldsFile.yml"
```

Follow this official documentation it contains  the exact answer I  hope  that it will help you:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-template.html

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your modules and fields.

There's are specific files called `fields.yml` (one global and one for each metricset), you have to fiddle with it.

Please refer to docs for details:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/configuration-metricbeat.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/5.2/creating-metricbeat-module.html#_fields_yml_2

Comment: Yea, thats the first think I did, I had to delete chunks from the fields yml to remove the mappings .. I was hoping that turning off and on the modules in the metricbeat.yml file, it wouldnt try to install the mappings. Thanks.